# If craven means "contemptibly lacking in courage," what do "craven desires" and "craven idols" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrase-usage

I was recently reviewing the meaning of the word **"craven,"** which included trying to find some good examples of its usage.  More often than not, I came across the phrases, **"craven desires"** and **"craven idols,"** neither of which seem to be using the definitions I find for "craven."  I am assuming that the word "craven" in these instances is acting more like a participle of some sort for the verb "to crave," but, thus far, I have not found any dictionary entry that alludes to this.  For phrases so common as "craven desires" and "craven idols" why do I not see some mention made of this?

---

Addendum:

Well, there's at least one decent answer in this thread that I will award the green checkmark to if no others surface, so I don't know how necessary this is at this point.  However, since I felt my initial question was sufficient and sense that others will, too, I will elaborate a bit to explain why I am adding to my original question.  First of all, I am really quite shocked that so many have never heard of the phrase "craven idol(s)" before.  (See comments below.)  I will wholeheartedly admit that I was unaware that it was a rock band and I did have to do some major revisions to my search parameters to finally get something that wasn't about that band.  Nevertheless, in my defense, I had heard or seen the phrase **"craven idols"** so long ago that I couldn't even tell you when it became part of my memory bank.  Not considering myself all that "well read," I was surprised to see that so many in this alleged erudite forum would be so dumbfounded by the phrase "craven idol."  But to suffice the skepticism of those below, what follows are some examples of the written word and its use of the phrase "craven idol(s)."  [I won't bother adding examples of "craven desires" because someone already took the time and trouble to do so (see the answers below)].  **Examples of craven idol and/or craven idols follow:**

> "Saint Paul makes the law of nature the basis for his claim that God can legitimately punish those who violate its precepts and inclinations.  He especially condemns the pagan practice of idol worship — of making God into the image of mortals, birds, and snakes.  Saint Paul is not referring to people who find themselves ignorant about the true God.  He addresses those whose personal wickedness compels them to reduce God to a **craven idol.**"
>
> **Source:** [***Praying with Saint Paul: Daily Reflections on the Letters of Saint Paul***](https://books.google.com/books?id=aAJeDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA5&dq=craven+idol+-county+-arrests+-wes+-music+-band+-CD+-shackles&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp6Nb786zZAhUL7mMKHdvAAw0Q6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=craven%20idol%20-county%20-arrests%20-wes%20-music%20-band%20-CD%20-shackles&f=false)
>
> "Garrett, damned to hell as he could well see, knew now, much to his horror, that Vanra's loyalty had been easily purchased.  The bodyguard's honour was swayed by gold alone and, alas, Garratt's reliance on the mere honour of the soldiering brotherhood could never topple that **craven idol** of greed."
>
> **Source:** [***Shadows Beneath the Watch Tower***](https://books.google.com/books?id=_wK-BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA164&dq=craven+idol+-county+-arrests+-wes+-music+-band+-CD+-shackles&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp6Nb786zZAhUL7mMKHdvAAw0Q6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=craven%20idol%20-county%20-arrests%20-wes%20-music%20-band%20-CD%20-shackles&f=false)
>
> "In some universities, lecturers fearful of sparking a suicide refuse to fail even the poorest students. "I often think of the implications for the student and the family before failing anyone," says one professor at Sogang University. But Korean students and their families, whose faith in the omnipotent powers of education is greater than in any other Confucian country in Asia, are worshipping a **craven idol**. If anyone takes too close a look at the system, they will be in for a rude awakening."
>
> **Source:** [***Korea Economic Report*, Vol. 8, p. 36**](https://books.google.com/books?id=EZS0AAAAIAAJ&q=craven+idol+-county+-arrests+-wes+-music+-band+-CD+-shackles&dq=craven+idol+-county+-arrests+-wes+-music+-band+-CD+-shackles&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjx1uX596zZAhUM82MKHVafBG84ChDoAQg3MAQ)

I see I still haven't added an example of "craven idol**s**" yet, so here's one more.  For the record, there were several I could have chosen.  I suppose this is as good as any:

> "These 'evil men who had been used to milking the villagers for years by parading bronze peacocks and other such **craven idols** among the villages and thus collecting large sums for their own use' had to be put down."
>
> **Source:** [***The Well-protected Domains: Ideology and the Legitimation of Power in the Ottoman Empire, 1876-1909***](https://books.google.com/books?id=tYsNAQAAMAAJ&q=craven+idols+-county+-arrests+-wes+-music+-band+-CD+-shackles&dq=craven+idols+-county+-arrests+-wes+-music+-band+-CD+-shackles&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM88Ph-qzZAhVB9WMKHdr6AcE4ChDoAQg9MAU)

Comment: Can you quote and link to some examples? I only find those terms as the names of a blogger and a heavy metal band, respectively (plus one article about a town in England named Craven); in other words, as nonsensical strings of words chosen for sound, rather than because they actually mean anything.

Comment: Is no one going to mention the phrase that OP actually heard was ***graven** idols*?

Comment: hey @DanBron - (1) yes, I mentioned that immediately in the first sentence of the answer :)  (2) nothing was "heard" - because (3) "craven idols" is (apparently) simply a business name, you can instantly google it (which the OP did - and confusingly thought it was an actual English phrase with meaning).

Comment: _Craven desires_ definitely exists as a phrase in English, but its usage cannot be harmonized easily with existing definitions. While _craven idols_ may only be a metal band, the usage with _desire_ certainly warrants a dscussion. The question should be reopened.

Comment: @1006a: on _craven desire_, use a minus sign (-bull, -pitbull, -Yorkshire) to eliminate false hits or use an NGram and follow those links.

Comment: @KarlG That's good advice—for the OP. If this is a real usage, it's the OP's responsibility to include evidence of that in the question.

Comment: It's really really stupid and small-minded that anyone should downvote a question that "now" has references and sources. I checked each link, and each one is valid. Don't like the question? Move along. Downvote Qs if they are low quality and do not share any research. This is not an example of  a LQQ.

Comment: @LisaBeck: These examples suggest to me that the authors are substituting _craven_ for the _graven_ of Scripture. It's not like these examples come from the top of the literary food chain. Desires, of course, can't be _graven_.

Comment: It is *not* 'Craven Idol! or image. It is *'Graven Idol!'* with a 'G' meaning, 'engraved or scratched' eg into stone, clay or wood. That's why you cannot find it - incorrect spelling - different word! 'Craven' is something else, which originally meant 'defeated or vanquished'. I'm having a hard time working out what 'craven desires' actually means.  It seems to mean 'debauched', 'immoral', or I thought it would be 'base', but I don't see how that arose from 'defeated and vanquished' - unless it means that one's *willpower* is defeated and vanquished - so you 'give in', or something...

Comment: Craven idiots? Ha ha are we...

Comment: It could be that the sense is so little used now that most English dictionaries, which unlike OED drop words / phrases / senses no longer regularly in use (according to their parameters), no longer consider it appropriate for inclusion. However, if OED doesn't include the sense, perhaps the editors need contacting to find out why.

Comment: I guess no one remembers the second commandment: Thou shalt not make unto thee any graven image. As in engraved in wood or stone. That's the only place I have ever heard it.....

Comment: @Lambie OP asks solely about a hard-to-find-a-definition-for sense of **craven**.

Comment: I'd say 'graven images' isn't commonly used nowadays, but it leaves 'craven desires' for dead according to [these Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=craven+desires%2Cgraven+images&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccraven%20desires%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgraven%20images%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth It's "graven image" (singular) specifically found in the Bible. The image is a major cliché and  ngrams are not relevant that for type of thing....I don't think. Anyone exposed to the King James version of the Bible knows it. (not the newer translations of it.) .

Comment: @Lambie 'It's "graven image" (singular) specifically found in the Bible.' makes as much sense in response to my comment addressed to you as 'It's the "Craven Heifer" where next week's darts match is being held'. I repeat, OP is asking about a sense of 'craven' meaning 'depraved, debauched' which isn't given in the free online dictionaries yet seems demanded by the reasonable quotes given in KarlG's answer.

Comment: ... But if you're saying that I have to choose 'graven image' rather than 'graven images' to compare frequency of use (with that of 'craven desires'), [these Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=graven+image%2Cgraven+images&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgraven%20image%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgraven%20images%3B%2Cc0) show that there's little difference. //  I've been advising people to change to a Bible in their language (rather than KingJamesspeak) for years. Verily.

Comment: I guess some authorities don't like singularities. Many Biblical clichés exist. And this is one of them. Here is a search from the American Bible Society with all the  translations recognized as authoritative: graven image; carved image or (just) the word idol. Like I said, ngram is not the proper search tool in this specific case.  In fact, in can even be misleading....http://bibles.org/search/graven%20image/eng-AMP,eng-ASV,eng-CEV,eng-CEVD,eng-ESV,eng-GNTD,eng-KJVA,eng-MSG,eng-NABRE,eng-NASB,eng-NIV,eng-NLT,eng-NRSV,eng-RSV,eng-T4T,eng-WEB,eng-WMB,eng-WMBBE/all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The Desires

The standard dictionary definition of *craven* is "[cowardly](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/craven?s=t)":

> This could be illustrated through Ancient History in the conduct of Ephialtes, the "Judas Iscariot" of Greece, who in satisfying his craven desires, brought untold misery to his fellow patriots by his treachery... [Henry Germanus Maeder, *Educational Outcomes Unique to Ancient History*, 1927](https://books.google.de/books?id=H5QBAAAAMAAJ&q=%22craven%20desires%22&dq=%22craven%20desires%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjn-_7l76PZAhVHDiwKHZJVAZYQ6AEIHDAA)

[Ephialtes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephialtes_of_Trachis) betrayed the united Greek forces to the Persians at Thermopylæ in hope of gain, his *craven*, i.e. cowardly desires. Greed in itself is not always cowardly, but accepting payment for betrayal, as Judas Iscariot, may certainly be deemed so.

In other usages, however, moral failings other than cowardice seem to be on the author's mind: *craven desires* are base, often debauched, and in the fiery rhetoric of Christian moralists, a grievous sin. For those wanting to perfume their otherwise wanting prose with a whiff of scandal, the word may equally serve.

> They laugh and dance, indulge and spend, and find some satisfaction in pursuing thrill, excitement, danger, popular acclaim, and material security. They follow their selfish instincts or yield to their craven desires. [Leslie F. Brandt, *Jesus/Now*, 1978.](https://books.google.de/books?id=gHOhSyGNkJsC&q=%22craven%20desires%22&dq=%22craven%20desires%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjn-_7l76PZAhVHDiwKHZJVAZYQ6AEIJjAC)
>
> Your religious training may have taught you that the body is a repository of base instincts and desires that must be repressed, ignored and squelched, lest you accede to your craven desires and spend eternity regretting the decision! [Ramón Stevens, *Whatever Happened to Divine Grace*, 1988.](https://books.google.de/books?id=nr0xu1s6kj8C&q=%22craven%20desires%22&dq=%22craven%20desires%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjo8mg96PZAhUD2ywKHasZBrYQ6AEIHDAA)

And now for someone apparently ready to chuck it all for (shudder!) one night of pleasure:

> She entered the living room in a most charming negligee. She had never interested me sexually in all the years I had known her — somehow I had never thought of her in that way. She had always been on a pedestal above all such craven desires. Her seductive negligee plus the liquor was sufficient for me to discover charms never before unfolded. [William Ward Smith, *A Letter from my Father*, 1976.](https://books.google.de/books?id=lioEAQAAIAAJ&q=%22craven%20desires%22&dq=%22craven%20desires%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjn-_7l76PZAhVHDiwKHZJVAZYQ6AEIOTAG)

This isn't cowardice; it's sex, drugs and rock 'n' roll. How lexicographers have missed this usage is beyond me, but only Superman-sized conceptual leaps can get to cowardice from charming, seductive negligees.

### Craven Desire in the Singular

*Craven desires* can just as easily be condemned in the singular, where the distance from the original meaning of "cowering, cowardly" is even more apparent. Occasionally, the familiar moral tone of the plural is still heard. Thus paraphrasing the Buddha:

> [the craven desire is the root of all suffering](https://books.google.de/books?id=L4-48cnprXoC&pg=PA17&lpg=PA17&dq=%22craven+desire%22&source=bl&ots=JsBSK80jbj&sig=x79v-GKN-9Vz3yGZat-ontWsLeU&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiForu74K7ZAhXBKewKHb2WAmAQ6AEwCXoECAwQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22craven%20desire%22&f=false)

And a Christian writer in an imaginary conversation with Hieronymus Bosch:

> [...the craven desire is for immediate gratification. It uses the other person, or thing, or even God, to meet this consummation of desire.](https://books.google.de/books?id=H9N2BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA91&lpg=PA91&dq=%22craven+desire%22&source=bl&ots=ZpcFl094mF&sig=F21pC7X4Fnq61CVa1NYbEvotaGg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi1pZjZ5q7ZAhXMyKQKHacTD2Y4ChDoATACegQIExAB)

This suggests a meaning of  *inordinate, selfish desire*, or, in a word, *lust*, which can be described negatively in countless scenarios without audible religious overtones. Thus a *craven desire*

> for [power](https://www.npr.org/2017/04/26/525575857/veep-executive-producer-on-making-a-show-about-the-craven-desire-for-power), again [here,](http://www.mystatesman.com/news/opinion/letters-the-editor-aug-2017/gCFPoFjlzFxGPRRYvwIRXI/) for [media attention,](https://medium.com/@JohntheCraptist/what-a-craven-crock-of-unadulterated-bullshit-d7a2e57a397c) [attention and power](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2008/10/27/grand-illusions-hilton-als), [money,](http://sentencedict.com/craven.html)  [to stay in power,](https://www.kenya-today.com/opinion/mr-president-stop-using-ongoing-food-shortage-campaign-tool) for [publicity](https://www.theguardian.com/uk/2001/feb/18/books.booksnews), [to be liked](https://ludwig.guru/s/desire+to+be+liked), [to seem young, purely for commercial purposes](http://www.esquire.com/entertainment/a4427/hannah-montana-0508/) (Hannah Montana), [to be provocative](http://www.rockremnants.com/category/ranking/) (Rolling Stones), or [to be on television](https://www.theringer.com/2018/1/8/16866038/bachelor-recap-season-22-episode-2-arie-krystal) (reality stars).

One writer turns to Norman Mailer for a [critique](http://thenewblackmagazine.com/view.aspx?index=1645) of the media in the run-up to the Second Gulf War:

> In an effort to analyze our wanton and exuberant Iraq war-lust, Mailer points to our *craven desire* for manipulated and televised displays of dominance as a major factor for the drive to the military invasion of Baghdad.

A journalist takes a look at the [1936 Berlin Olympics](http://chronicleillinois.com/news/cook-county-news/museums-team-up-to-bring-light-to-1936-olympics/) and

> the Germans' *craven desire* to paint a sanitized picture of their society to a skeptical world.

While *craven* is never completely free of opprobrium, there are cases where the desire is neither overwhelming nor morally suspect, merely very strong. Thus a business has a *craven desire* to [win over consumers](https://gizmodo.com/htc-10-review-a-last-grasp-at-greatness-1770943344) or [fill a niche market](https://www.marketingweek.com/2017/08/30/mark-ritson-personal-branding/), and the director of the film *Benjamin Button* has a [*craven desire*](http://collider.com/the-curious-case-of-benjamin-button-review/) to elicit emotion.

One writer suggests that US senators' reluctance to use email comes from their [*craven desire*](http://www.chicagotribune.com/news/opinion/commentary/ct-email-senators-offline-dinosaurs-perspec-0318-20150317-story.html) to avoid record-keeping, while the Far Right in the US has a [*craven desire*](https://katz.sas.upenn.edu/content/response-charlottesville) for academic acceptance.

Finally, a self-designated perfectionist has a [*"craven desire*](http://mindmeldcoaching.com/notes-from-a-recovering-perfectionist/)  to do everything perfectly the first time" and a woman in India describes humorously her [*craven desire*](http://www.sandhyaacharya.com/2016/08/09/michael-kors-jhola-and-i/) for a Michael Kors handbag.

No stretch of the imagination can inject cowardice into any of these usages of *craven*.

## The Idols

*Craven idol* received no hits in a Google NGram; a collocation search only yielded results such as *fear/fears*, unambiguously in the sense of 'cowardly.' Since *Craven Idol* is also the name of a heavy metal band, googling becomes a frustrating exercise in using the minus sign. What non-metalic results appear, however, suggest that the band is not using a nonce word for its name.

A *Time Magazine* [review](http://content.time.com/time/magazine/article/0,9171,872229,00.html) (31 Mar 1961) of a decidedly anti-modernist book by Robert Elliot Fitch, Dean of the Pacific School of Religion, is entitled *The Craven Idol*.

The Golden Calf of the Exodus saga is *craven*:

> But there in that wilderness/
>   before the craven idol/
>   before the king demanding to be god/
>   Refusing to bow, to deny the creator/
>   honoring the words written so long ago/
>   Prepared to be burned, to submit to the furnace/
>   entering in, faithful to God.  [Raymond A. Foss, The First Commandment, 2009.](https://www.inspirationalstories.com/poems/the-first-commandment-raymond-a-foss-poem/)
>
> God was about to destroy the children of Israel because of their craven idol that [they] had made and also because of Aaron's sin. [Erica Michael, *Birthing His Glory Through Dance, Part 1, 2010.*](https://books.google.de/books?id=mMiSBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=%22craven+idol%22+-mammon+-metal+-song+-band+-album+-eschaton+-Musik+-music&source=bl&ots=LFBa08sys0&sig=EWc1E9ZfHRgK1savmL_ldtqcEbw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjj1vScqq7ZAhWRDOwKHecOBGk4ChDoATAFegQICRAB)

Foss also alludes to the statue of the Roman emperor to which Christians were to pay homage or suffer punishment.

In [*The Invisible Dragon: Essays on Beauty, Revised and Expanded*, 2012](https://books.google.de/books?id=pz235TSlnMYC&pg=PT112&lpg=PT112&dq=%22craven+idol%22+-mammon+-metal+-song+-band+-album+-eschaton+-Musik+-music&source=bl&ots=YUlDBbavSV&sig=2odLDftMf3CI1KlDcqGxrnM8DCM&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjj1vScqq7ZAhWRDOwKHecOBGk4ChDoATACegQIERAB#v=onepage&q=%22craven%20idol%22%20-mammon%20-metal%20-song%20-band%20-album%20-eschaton%20-Musik%20-music&f=false), author Dave Hickey describes a painting of Jesus, which

> ... thanks to oil glazing, seems an uncanny incarnation of Christ? Is it a picture, an icon, a craven idol, or something else?

A four-item catalogue such as this is the last place one would expect an affect-laden or polemic adjective, though *idol* is the only noun that gets any adjective at all. Whatever the intentions of the author, pausing in the middle of a list to comment on the "cowardly" nature of a cultic statue is not likely to be among them.

Almost all of these uses of *craven*, whether collocated with *desires* or *idol*, come from literature with an overtly religious stance, or certainly a moral one.

For the prophet Habakkuk (2.18), *graven* or *molten* images are made from human hands: they are "dumb," inert stone or metal incapable of speech. In 1 Cor. 12.2, they are merely "dumb idols." It would be difficult to imagine a writer of devotional literature ascribing any affect at all to an idol, even a negative one such as cowardice.

### The Dilemma

*Craven desires* and *craven idol* seem to inhabit the same Christian moral and polemic universe, yet the usual definition of *craven* as "cowardly" is a poor fit for either. A meaning of "depraved, debauched" might work for *desires*, but not for idols. Try as I might, I can only see the use of *craven* for idols as a strange variant of *graven*, even by those intimate with the latter term from the Hebrew and Greek Scriptures.

The parallel of *bronze peacocks* and *craven idols* in the Ottoman history would suggest an adjective equally parallel to bronze, and none of the sources for *craven idol* would suffer in the least were *graven* used in its stead.

The use of the singular diverges just as strongly from dictionary entries, yet it's clear that the word *craven* is being used in ways other than that prescribed. Perhaps *craven* suggests to some speakers an excessive *craving* for most any desired object, which can be acknowledged but not necessarily condemned. The disparity between living language and lexicography for this word, however, remains an intriguing dilemma.

Comment: Appreciate the time/effort you put into this answer. All things considered, you may walk away with the green checkmark. The best part of your answer, to me, however, is when you acknowledge that it is something of a mystery how lexicographers missed this usage. Perhaps they are too busy adding new words like "selfie-stick" to the dictionary.  I'm holding out for someone who might be able to address that aspect a bit more thoroughly. (If that's you even better!)  If not, you certainly have answered the question best.  But considering the question has been put on hold, somewhat of a moot point.

Comment: @LisaBeck: Three users, including me, have voted to reopen the question. Only two more are required. I _only_ knew this word in its "fire and brimstone" sense and was surprised that wasn't reflected in dictionaries.

Comment: There are many more hits on the internet for 'secret desires'. These may be collocations, but they are transparent and hardly more than adjective + noun strings.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth:  The point is about the lexical disparity between dictionary definitions and actual usage, at least for me. Why should "many more hits for 'secret desires'" be more relevant here than more for "potato salad"?

Comment: @KarlG Excellent news about the voting system.  I'm about to turn to other things now and not sure when I will be back.  Maybe I will be met with good news when I return.  Perhaps I should cravenly pray to the solemn and wise Idol of Question Reopener.

Comment: I'm saying that 'craven desires' could easily be read as 'desires one is too fearful to yield to'. Rather like 'a proud day': a transferred epithet. Until a definition for _craven_ such as 'base, wicked' is found in an accepted reference work, I think this has to be classed as POB.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Please see the examples I added in the singular.

Comment: Graven image is in the second commandment. It just rings in my head and no one has even mentioned  it....And I am not especially Bible prone...

Comment: @Lambie: I assumed it was so obvious I didn't need to mention it. In the traditions with which I'm most familiar (Lutheran, Catholic), that verse is still part of the First Commandment. But this is part of the dilemma, why would someone use the word _craven_ in a poem about the First Commandment no matter where the verses are divided, when the word _graven_ is right in front of his nose?

Comment: I think the good father  made a mistake in that phrase ( I had a look at the link). The first commandment is Thou shall have no other God but me or before me.  But there are variations  in different branches/denominations. For many other Protestants, it's two.

Comment: @KarlG  The paragraph that begins, “Ephialtes betrayed …” is precisely the type of explanation I was hoping to find for this question. In fact, I could have stopped there and awarded you the green checkmark, but instead, your thoroughness in research intrigued me and compelled me to continue reading. I then came upon, “No stretch of the imagination can inject cowardice into any of these usages of craven,” which hammered in yet another solid nail onto your green checkmark.

Comment: @KarlG  Glad you included a ref to the commandments because truth be told I believe this phrase — craven idols — first came to be lodged in my memory through some connection related to that sense of its usage, and perhaps the Golden Calf specifically. I had run across the example you included from _The Invisible Dragon_ and your comment about it made me chuckle out loud.

Comment: @KarlG  But perhaps best of all was your closing paragraph where you acknowledge that “craven” may mean to some “an excessive craving for most any desired object,” if, for no other reason, than it seems to be a logical fit in many of the contexts that simply do not seem to jive with the meaning of cowardly.  Overall, extremely well done effort, KarlG, and most deserving of the coveted, and perhaps even craven, green checkmark.

Comment: @KarlG, you said, *A meaning of "depraved, debauched" might work for desires, but not for idols.* I can imagine, however, in the *Christian moral and polemic universe* (which I inhabit) preachers and moralists using "craven" in the sense of "depraved, debauched" when referring to idols, due primarily to the frequent diatribes found in the OT prophetic writings. That is to say, an idol that causes people to become depraved in their worship and debauched in their behavior may, by association, itself be considered "craven". BTW, great answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, you're all out to lunch. The idols are graven (carved) not craven. Misheard, misspelled, misused....please do not ever write craven idols. The rock band's name was clearly a joke, which apparently nobody gets.. I feel sorry for the word craven, now used to mean corrupt although for centuries it had a plain meaning: cowardly, weak and slavish. And now this!
Pls see Exodus 20 4-6 for the graven images.

Comment: My thoughts entirely. The use of "craven" idols is an eggcorn or simple ignorance or a misprint. Eggcorn: https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/most-misused-phrases-words-english-language-uk-revealed-be-pacific-a8098791.html

Answer (score -2):

They mean desires and idols that are [craven](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/craven) (contemptibly lacking in courage; cowardly).  Idols are not actually alive, so any "desires" they have  can be described as *craven*. Also, *Craven Idol* is the name of a rock band; and pretty much anything goes when it comes to names; they don't have to "make sense" or be common phrases (examples: Smashing Pumpkins, Goo Goo Dolls, Mr. Mister, Limp Bizkit; [your mileage may vary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ymmv); and I am not knocking any of the named bands).

The same can be said of "craven desires," and the good old *Guardian* has made a pun on the phrase in its article:

*[Craven desires: why living in the Yorkshire Dales makes you happy](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/shortcuts/2017/sep/27/craven-desires-why-living-in-the-yorshire-dales-makes-you-happy)*

Here, *Craven* is apparently "a local government district of North Yorkshire." But the people of Craven, or perhaps Craven itself, can have desires. Perhaps this is a reference to the other Craven Desires that is on the internet, which seems to be some kind of [controversial blogger](https://pitbullhaterexposed.blogspot.com/2017/08/dawn-james-craven-desires-is-fake.html).